# Fetch json logs between date and timestamp range

Tags: linux, shell-script

My log file sample (its in json format):

```
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:01.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:01.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:05],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:32:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:02.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:02.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:06],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:32:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:03.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:03.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:07],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:34:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:04.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:04.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:08],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:34:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:05.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:05.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:09],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:35:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:06.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:06.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:10],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:35:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:07.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:07.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:11],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:36:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:08.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:08.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:11],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:36:37.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:09.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:09.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:12],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:37:10.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:10.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:10.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:13],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:37:15.8",somecontent
```

This log file is having timestamps in no of places, but I have to compare the timeline of last "timestamp".

I have spent lot of time, but I didn't find the solution.

I have tried following commands.

```
cat test | grep '"timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:32:35.8"'
```

This is fetching a single line which is matching this criteria.

```
cat test | sed -n -e '/"timestamp":/p' ->
```

This is listing the lines where the criteria matches "timestamp"

```
cat test | sed -n "/23:32/,/23:36/ p" | egrep "manivel"
```

This one collecting the logs between two timestamps, and grep criteria. But its not considering the last timestamp in the log file.

I'm not posting this without doing any research.

The problem is this log file is having the string "timestamp" on no of places and time (T09:15:06.000Z) like this in no of places on single line.

That's where I'm struck. Your expertise answer would be really appreciated and save my time.

Comment: Is this a JSON file? Use JSON tools, not line-based tools, to extract data out of JSON files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, its json file. Is it not possible using shell script ?
If not can you please recommend any tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to print the lines where the last timestamp (immediately following the "timestamp" string) is between two specified times. I'll assume the lines are in time order.

```
$ sed -n '/"timestamp":"[^"]*T23:32:/,/"timestamp":"[^"]*T23:36:/p' test
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:01.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:01.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:05],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:32:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:02.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:02.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:06],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:32:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:03.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:03.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:07],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:34:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:04.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:04.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:08],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:34:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:05.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:05.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:09],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:35:35.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:06.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:06.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:10],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:35:36.8",somecontent
somecontent"TransDateTime\":\"2020-07-01T09:15:07.000Z","receiveTimestamp":"2020-07-01T02:15:07.335142083Z","textPayload":"[7/1/20 23:11],","timestamp":"2020-07-01T23:36:36.8",somecontent
```

Let me break this down to explain. By specifying `"timestamp"` in the match strings, you are ensuring that the times to be matched are the ones after `"timestamp"`.

The sequence `[^"]*` means any characters that are not quotes. The reason for this is to ensure that a new field is not added in future lines, between the `"timestamp"` string and the timestamp itself.

I use the match string `T23:36:` rather than just `23:36` so that it doesn't accidentally match something minutes and seconds, like in `23:23:36.8`.

Note that this will print all lines between the first line that matches the first match string, and the first line that matches the last match string. So in this example, there are two lines with timestamp "23:35" but only the first is printed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jezzaaaa, i will try this and update you the status.

Comment: Your command helped me to add into my script and you saved my life. Thanks a ton for your help.
I need to add Start date and End date in my script instead on "Date" parameter. Is there any chance i can do in this script. 
As stated earlier i have search on .json file. The file format is like "00:00:00_00:59:59*.json", "01:00:00_01:59:59*.json" like this for every hour in the same format. 
I tried with "for loop" with "printf '%02d'" option, the problem is its not continuing the loop after 07, because it take 08 as hexa decimal value. Please assist me if possible.
Thank you!

Comment: #!/bin/bash
set +x
DTE=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y-v%H%m%s")
Date=$1
Keyword=$2
Start_Time=$3
End_Time=$4
BKT=storage/folder
d=$1
y1=$(sed 's/.\{6\}$//' <<< "$d") 
m1=$(cut -c 6-7 <<< "$d") 
d1=$(sed -r 's/^.{8}//' <<< "$d") 
i=$3
i1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$i") 
j=$4
j1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$j") 
output=$(gsutil cat -h gs://storage/folder/"$y1"/"$m1"/"$d1"/"$i1:00:00_$j1:59:59*" | sed -n '/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$i':/,/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$j':/p' | egrep '$Keyword')
echo $output >> $"/tmp/localfolder/logfile-$DTE"
gsutil cp -r /tmp/folder/logfile-$DTE gs://newstorage/folder/

Comment: @Mani, I'm not sure what you mean with the for loop and printf. Can you show what you tried to do, describe what the result was, and describe the result you expected?

Comment: if you see the current script, i have the variable Date=$1. Instead of single date variable i wanted to add 2 variables like "Start_Date" and "End_Date", so that the log can be searched between 2 dates.  
I thought to add this condition in the loop, so i tried for loop condition. When the looping happens, its not happening beyond "07". Can you suggest me anyway to compare the logs between 2 dates. Please let me know if any clarifications needed.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared following script to collect the logs between date and timestamp along with keyword.
The reason for posting here is, it might help someone who is looking for similar script.

`#!/bin/bash`
`set +x`
`DTE=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y-v%H%m%s")`
`startdate=$1`
`enddate=$2`
`start_Time=$3`
`end_Time=$4`
`keyword=$5`
`BKT=storage/folder`
`i=$start_time`
`i1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$i")`
`j=$end_time`
`j1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$j")`
`curr="$startdate"`
`while true; do`
`echo "$curr"`
`[ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break`
`output=$(gsutil cat -h gs://storage/folder/"$curr"/"$i1:00:00_$j1:59:59*" | sed -n '/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$i':/,/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$j':/p' | grep "$keyword")`
`echo $output >> $"/tmp/folder/mylog-$DTE"`
`curr=$( date +%Y/%m/%d --date "$curr +1 day" )`
`done`
`gsutil cp -r /tmp/folder/mylog-$DTE gs://storage/folder/`

Thank you @jezzaaaa for your sed command.